# off vs of vs off of - Can they be interchanged

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

A colleague wrote the following to me :

> I am making a conscious endeavor to clear my mind off trivial thoughts.

Though I read and understood the meaning, what rang a bell was the usage of *off*.

I have searched online and it appears to me that *all of the below are correct*:

> - I am making a conscious endeavor to clear my mind **off** trivial thoughts
> - I am making a conscious endeavor to clear my mind **of** trivial thoughts
> - I am making a conscious endeavor to clear my mind **off of**  trivial thoughts.

Please correct me!

Comment: Also see EL&U: *[Difference between get “off of” and “off”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101683)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Er, only the second sentence is correct. I guess the third sentence is *technically* grammatically correct, but it uses the phrase "off of" completely incorrectly. 
I have a feeling that your colleague made a typographical or spelling mistake.

"Off" and "of" not only have different definitions, they are pronounced differently. "Off" is pronounced with a short "o" sound ("lot, chopped") while the "o" in "of" is pronounced with a more throaty "uhh" sound ("some, gun")

"Off" is a descriptor and can be used as a preposition (which is the role it serves in the phrase "off of "). It can be used to describe an inactive state for a machine or device of some kind, and it can also be used as a point of reference for "not resting on something." (i.e. "Get off of the counter!")

Meanwhile, "of" is the word that links many prepositional phrases together, as seen above. I'm not very well-educated when it comes to "low-level" words like "of", so I'll let someone else explain it in more detail.

> I am making a conscious endeavor to clear my mind off trivial thoughts.

This makes sense until we reach the last three words. "Clear my mind off?" Makes about as much sense as "clear my mind on."

> I am making a conscious endeavor to clear my mind off of trivial thoughts.

This almost makes sense, but where "of" would normally indicate what is leaving the speaker's mind, it is instead linked to "off" in the prepositional phrase, "off of trivial thoughts." This, however, would make sense:

> Get your mind off of trivial thoughts and get back to work.

While rude, this is a proper usage of the same phrase in a different sentence.

Comment: To my (American) ear, "off" sounds like the first syllable in "awful", and "of" sounds like the end of "love".

Comment: Yes, that's another way to put it. I'm no linguist, so I don't know how different the vowel sounds in "lot" and "awful" are from one another, but they sound almost identical to me.

Comment: @CrazyEyes In many dialects the vowels are not so clearly distinguished. But I believe that in **all** native-speaker dialects the consonants are distinguished: /v/ in *of*, /f/ in *off*.

Answer (score 2):

Of the three choices in the original post, only "clear my mind **of** trivial thoughts" sounds correct to my (American) ear.

On the other hand, the following two sentences are correct:

> I am making a conscious endeavor to **get** my mind **off** trivial thoughts.
>
> I am making a conscious endeavor to **get** my mind **off of** trivial thoughts.

"clear... of" and "get... off of" sound the most natural to me.

Comment: As you imply, the verb *clear* requires *of*. Clear the table of dishes.  The verb *get* (in this context) takes *off of*. Get your mind off of sex and concentrate on your studies!