# "Reflection off of surfaces" vs "Reflection of surfaces" vs "Reflection off surfaces"

Tags: grammar

In this [link](https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-3/Reflection,-Refraction,-and-Diffraction) I came across this sentence:

> 1 Reflection of sound waves off of surfaces can lead to one of two phenomena.

Is it a grammatical sentence? Isn't the usage of "off of" a little bit awkward?

Are the following sentences grammatical? Are they also better choices?

> 2 Reflection of sound waves off surfaces can lead to one of two phenomena.

> 3 Reflection of sound waves of surfaces can lead to one of two phenomena.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [off vs of vs off of - Can they be interchanged](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36960/off-vs-of-vs-off-of-can-they-be-interchanged). Also ["Work off" vs. "work off of"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/311213/) and ["On" vs. "Off of" vs. "Off"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93347/) and [The usage of "Off"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155376/the-usage-of-off), among others.

Comment: "Reflection of sound waves of surfaces" doesn't work because it sounds like the sound waves belong to the surface somehow.

Comment: You can use *off*, but I think *by* works better. It points to a function more than a direction, but it fits.

Answer (score -3):

A sound waves bounces off a surface:

> Sound waves can
> bounce off smooth, hard objects in the same way as a
> rubber ball bounces off the ground.

[sounds](https://www.dkfindout.com/us/science/sound/echoes/)

It is **off the surface** because it is not **on the surface.**

A ball can bounce on a hard surface.
A ball bounced on a board can fly off the surface (away from in the air).

Likewise,  "Reflection of sound waves off of surfaces can lead to one of two phenomena".

If reflects **off the surface** (away from) because it does not say on that surface.

off=away from, not on.

BLOG:

Observations on British and American English by an American linguist in the UK

> Andy S wrote to say: I'm interested in the Americanism off of which
> sounds very odd to British ears. I'd be interested to know more about
> it. Indeed, Americans would often get off of a [much more common in
> AmE--in BrE it can have a more restricted meaning] couch, whereas
> British folk would get off the [available in AmE, but I suspect that
> the frequency varies regionally] sofa.  That's not to say that off of
> is the only way we put it in AmE, as evidenced by  Paul Simon's
> admonition to Gus to hop off the bus.  And Americans didn't make it
> up.  In the OED, one can find the following examples:
>
> a1616 SHAKESPEARE Henry VI, Pt. 2 (1623) II. i. 98 **A fall off of a
> Tree.** 1667
> A. MARVELL Corr. in Wks. (1875) II. 224 The Lords and we
> cannot yet **get off of the difficultyes** risen betwixt us.
>
> Nevertheless, it *came to be regarded* as 'non-standard' in Britain.
> In AmE (according to Random House Webster's College Dictionary, 1991
> [via Fowler's Modern English Usage, 3rd edn]), off of is 'widespread
> in speech, including that of the educated . . . but is **rare in
> edited writing'.**
> **But, in a weird twist, AmE speakers are more likely to say go out the window/door than BrE speakers, who more typically go out of the
> window.**

[Separated by a Common Language](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/)

Comment: I can only conclude an anti-American bias. But I truly do not care. :)